# Generating a series of numbers nearest to the hundred of another number

Tags: java

I have here a series of integers as follows:

```
x: [100,200,300,341]
```

I want to print another column y that gives the following result:

```
y:[1,101,201,301]
```

So basically the nearest hundred except for the last

Another example is as follows:

```
x:[100,200,300,400,454]

y:[1,101,201,301,401]
```

I want a way to store such values in v with respect to each value in x in the corresponding index

Comment: Didn't get that. What is the problem?

Comment: 500 is the nearest hundred for 454, so your instructions are not really clear.

Comment: sorry about that. I am not much of a mathematician so I don't know the exact wording of my problem if it exists at all

Comment: This is basically rounding down to the nearest hundred, with one added: `nearest = ((x - 1) / 100) * 100 + 1`.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard That is absolutely correct. I just tested it out. Why don't you answer it formally in the section below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adrians formula works:

```
public class Hundred {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x.add(100);
        x.add(200);
        x.add(300);
        x.add(400);
        x.add(454);

        for (Integer xx : x) {
            int nearest = ((xx - 1) / 100) * 100 + 1;
            System.out.println(nearest);
        }
    }
}
```

results in:

1
101
201
301
401

Comment: `Arrays.asList(100, 200, 300, 400, 454)` btw.

Comment: thx Adrian - you're right. I won't change my answer because it's already accepted.